# UI5 oData binding: Bind property of parent note when using associations

Tags: binding, odata, sapui5

I have an entity set for employees (EmployeeSet) with an association to further details.

`EmployeeSet(1)` holds the data for one employee and is bound to a detail view. Inside this view I'm using a form to bind the further details with an association called `ToFurtherDetails`.

No I need one property from `EmployeeSet(1)` inside this form.

Is there a way to bind a property from a parent node?

Comment: What kind of view is that? Have you set the EmployeeSet as Item onto it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use the *expand* Parameter to request the `ToFurtherDetails` from the OData Service.

For example you bind your EmployeeSet in the Master-View like this:

`<List id="list" items="{ path: '/EmployeeSet', parameters: {expand : 'ToFurtherDetails'} }" itemPress="handleSelect" />`

Now you are able to access the `ToFurtherDetails` in your Detail-View like this `/EmployeeSet(1)/ToFurtherDetails`

Comment: I know this way, but is there also a way the other way round. For example if In JavaScript I can do something like this `this.getParent().getContextBinding()`. I'm looking for a solution doing this via xml. Any idea?

Comment: No, there is no other way when you only want to use xml. And by the way my approach is also only via xml. Why do you don't want to use it?

Comment: It's because I have to do a bindElement and cannot use an expand parameter due to the fact, that I have a 1:N relation, but only need one element at a time based on given keys.